# Substract Flag From FontStyle (Toggling FontStyles) [C#]

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, textbox, richtextbox

I have a little problem. I have one 1 RichTextBox and 2 Buttons.

I have that 2 buttons for "toggle Bold FStyle" and "toggle Italic FStyle".

I want to toggle FontStyles without affecting other FontStyles. I hope you understand me.

Below code works when **combining** FontStyles but **is not working when seperating/substracting FontStyles**.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, (richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Bold == false ? richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Bold : richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style));
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, (richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Italic == false ? richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Italic : richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style));
}
```

1. I make selected text Bold
2. I make selected text Italic
3. I want to remove Italic while Bold is still active (or opposite)

Comment: A similar approach to the solution for this also applies to `TextBox` controls.  See my comment in the answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way is to use bitwise XOR (`^`), which just toggles the value:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font,
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style ^ FontStyle.Bold);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font,
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style ^ FontStyle.Italic);
}
```

Comment: Watchout ! If the current text selection has more than one font, SelectionFont will be null http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.RICHTEXTBOX.SELECTIONFONT);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true

Comment: A similar approach also works with `TextBox` controls.  The difference being that `SelectionFont` in the above example would need to be changed to `Font`.