# How to make some text bold in a rich text box in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf, bold

I want to create a text editor where I can make text bold, change its color, etc.

I found this code to approximately work:

```
public static void BoldSelectedText(RichTextBox control)
{
     control.SelectionFont = new Font(control.Font.FontFamily, control.Font.Size,         FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

But when I type in more letters in the `RichTextBox` the text is still bold.

How can I make it so that only the selected text is bold and the next characters aren't unless I select the text and hit the "Make Bold" button?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should set the font after the selection to the original font.

If you want you can save the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` and call the `Select` method to select the text again.

```
// Remember selection
int selstart = control.SelectionStart;
int sellength = control.SelectionLength;

// Set font of selected text
// You can use FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic to apply more than one style
control.SelectionFont = new Font(control.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

// Set cursor after selected text
control.SelectionStart = control.SelectionStart + control.SelectionLength;
control.SelectionLength = 0;
// Set font immediately after selection
control.SelectionFont = control.Font;

// Reselect previous text
control.Select(selstart, sellength);
```

this way the text stays selected, and the font afterwards is still correct.

Comment: Do you know how i can bold and italic text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198429/substract-flag-from-fontstyle-toggling-fontstyles-c that helped

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but for the benefit of others, FontStyle has the Flags attribute, so you can do things like FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic, etc.

Comment: I think this is a tad outdated.. It only keeps the text BEFORE the bold text's font, but the text thereafter is also bold, which I assume is not how this is supposed to go..