# Get marked text in a textbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I get the text that the user marked so I can bolden only the marked text instead of bolding up the whole textbox text?I don't know how to formulate my statement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String data=TextBox1.SelectedText;
```

for Formatting the Text like setting the Selected Text to Bold or to Specific font you Should Use RichTextBoxControl.

Example:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: This does not answer "bolden only the marked text instead of bolding up the whole textbox text?"

Comment: Hello thanks alot about this but I want to use a textbox and textbox does not include the selectionfont prop

Comment: Textbox doesnt support rich text.

Comment: ^this explains a lot! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you would be using a RichTextBox control. you need to highlight the word and make it bold.

[How to make some text bold in a rich text box C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923919/how-to-make-some-text-bold-in-a-rich-text-box-c-sharp)

Comment: welcome. feel free to mark it as an answer